# Execute code below only when Rasdial process completed

Tags: c#, multithreading, vpn

As per title, I'll be creating a rasdial connection like below:-

```
Process.Start("rasdial.exe", "\"connection\" username pasword");

//Other tasks...
```

Works fine, however, I wanted a successful connection first before the code below is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write like this:

```
Process process = Process.Start("rasdial.exe", "\"connection\" username pasword");
process.WaitForExit();
```

Then [`WaitForExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) call will wait until rasdial process is closed.